# Trying to get RodeCaster Pro to work with Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: sound

Hello I am trying to get my Rodecaster pro to work with Ubuntu.  I can see my list of usb devices with lsusb.

The Rodecaster is listed under there, but I cannot get it to show up anywhere else, specifically in OBS.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

This should work with a linux-5.7 kernel and above.